# WPF Popup UI showing black

Tags: wpf, user-interface, popup

I am using a WPF Popup control, and it is showing the background as black. I put a StackPanel inside it with Background="Transparent", but that does not help.

```
<Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=parentStackPanel}" Placement="Center"
        IsOpen="False" Name="m_popWaitNotifier" PopupAnimation="None" 
        AllowsTransparency="False">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="Transparent">
        <uc:CircularProgressBar x:Name="CB" StartupDelay="0"
                                            RotationsPerMinute="20"
                                            Height="25" Foreground="White"
                                            Margin="12"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Popup>
```

How does one make the background on Popup transparent (or any color)?

Comment: Please post some example XAML.  What you describe isn't default behavior, but it is difficult to say much more about it without knowing how you define it.

Comment: @PN As an aside -- If you add code, please select (highlight) it, and select the "code" button above the edit textbox.  This will format the code to be much more readable.

Comment: What happens if you add the CircularProgressBar control directly to a window (as a test).  Could the Black background be coming from that?

Answer (score 93):

You need to set the `AllowsTransparency="True"` Popup Property to True

Here is an example:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
    <Button Click="Button_Click" Width="100" Height="20" Content="Click" />
        <Popup x:Name="popup" Width="100" Height="100" AllowsTransparency="True">
            <Grid Background="Transparent">
                <TextBlock Text="Some Text" />
            </Grid>
        </Popup>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

and the click handler

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    popup.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    popup.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Comment: Hi Svetlozar: I tried this but it does not work. For me though I do not have a StackPanel outside the Popup, but I have a StackPanel within the Popup that holds a couple of control on it.

Comment: Man, you're golden. Why does it have this strange default behavior? I lost my nerve trying to understand what's happening...

Answer (score 17):

The base color of a `Popup`, or a `Window` for that matter, is black.  You rarely see it for a  `Window` because `Window` has a `Background` property and it defaults to a solid color, but if you set `Window.Background` to `Transparent` it will also be black.  But `Popup` doesn't have a `Background` property and so, pardon the pun, this problem "pops up".

If you want the `Popup` to be transparent, you need to set `AllowsTransparency="True"`.  However, if you want the `Popup` to be a solid color, the simplest approach is to make the child of the `Popup` a `Panel` that supports the `Background` property and set that property to the color you desire and then set the child of the `Panel` to be the content you intended for the `Popup` in the first place.  I suggest `Grid` as it won't affect the layout of your `Popup`.  It's only effect will be to give you the background color you desire.

Comment: man I wish I used the right search terms earlier.  I was stuck thinking it was stuff in the popup that was causing my black background. Once I finally searched right and landed on this page, This is definitely THE answer

Comment: If you want that Grid takes the default Background color you can use: <Grid Background="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrush}">

Answer (score 11):

Make sure that the allow transparency is set to true, vertical and horizontal alignments are centered, and the height and width are set to Auto.

For example:

```
<Popup Name="popup1" Placement="Top" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=button2}" AllowsTransparency="True" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Panel.ZIndex="1" HorizontalOffset="-5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">

<StackPanel Height="92" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="93,522,0,0" Name="stackPanelPop" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="147">
</StackPanel>

</Popup>
```

Answer (score 7):

Another possible cause:

- using IsOpen="True" in markup before AllowTransparency="True"

Switching the order fixes it.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that the CircularProgressBar is actually causing the Black background.  The only other way that this could happen is if there was a Style or something set on one of the controls (Popup or StackPanel or...).

Here is a quick-n-dirty example that shows a TextBlock in a popup when a checkbox is checked.  The colors chosen are just to make sure things stand out visually:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="stackPanelLayout">
    <StackPanel.Background>
        <RadialGradientBrush Center="0.75, 0.75"
                             SpreadMethod="Reflect">
            <GradientStop Color="LightBlue" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="SeaGreen" Offset="0.5" />
            <GradientStop Color="MidnightBlue" Offset="0.75" />
        </RadialGradientBrush>
    </StackPanel.Background>


    <CheckBox x:Name="chkShowPopup"
              FontSize="20"
              Foreground="White"
              Content="Show Popup" />

    <Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=stackPanelLayout}" 
           Placement="Center" 
           IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=chkShowPopup, Path=IsChecked}" 
           Name="m_popWaitNotifier" 
           PopupAnimation="Slide"
           AllowsTransparency="True">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="Transparent">
            <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold" Text="PopUp" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Popup>
</StackPanel>
```

So, two tests you can do to determine what is happening:

1. Replace the CircularProgressBar with a simple TextBlock or other control that you don't have a Style applied to.
2. Put the CircularProgressBar as a standalone control somewhere on your window, or on an otherwise blank test Window.

Answer (score 2):

As per this article [Why is my WPF Popup black and how do I get it positioned properly?](http://blog.scrappydog.com/2009/02/why-is-my-wpf-popup-black-and-how-do-i.html) 
:

You need to set the AllowsTransparency property on the Popup to True, and set the PlacementTarget and Placement properties to control the position the Popup opens in.

As per the code in question:

```
<Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=parentStackPanel}" Placement="Center" IsOpen="False" Name="m_popWaitNotifier" PopupAnimation="None" AllowsTransparency="False">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="Transparent">
       <uc:CircularProgressBar x:Name="CB" StartupDelay="0" RotationsPerMinute="20" Height="25" Foreground="White" Margin="12"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Popup>
```

the PlacementTarget is set to parentStackPanel, whereas the questioner has mentioned:

> Hi Svetlozar: I tried this but it does
>   not work. For me though I **do not** have
>   a StackPanel **outside** the Popup, but I
>   have a StackPanel within the Popup
>   that holds a couple of control on it

The problem could be that Popup **could not find** the PlacementTarget 'parentStackPanel' because it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the grid is not orientation places it outside of the popup.
Remove  VerticalAlignment and horizontalAlignment from all the controls inside the popup, and it will work correctly

Answer (score 0):

Quite old, but may help someone: Add `InitializeComponent();` in the constructor, it solved my problem:

```
class MyPopupClass : Popup {
    /*
    ...
    */
    public MyPopupClass () {
        InitializeComponent();
        /*
        ...
        */
    }
    /*
    ...
    */
}
```

Comment: @WoIIe, thanks for the feedback. I'd be glad to learn what's my mistake. It worked for me, so what do I miss?

Comment: I am sorry for writing such a rude comment. I just don't think that your answer can help the OP in any way to solve his problem. One reason is that `InitializeComponent()`-Method is autogenerated into the constructor and totally necessary for a `Control` or `FrameWorkelement` to work in an WPF app. There is absolutely no reason to delete this line. You also have written code, that shows a custom implementation of the `Popup`-control, which isn't the case for the OP. Since he uses the normal `Popup` class, there is no way that he forgot the `this.InializeComponent()`-method for his Popup.

Comment: @WoIIe, yep, I completely agree.